# What does webpack mean by XX hidden modules

Tags: javascript, build, webpack

I've been playing with webpack and during the build I see it output:
`+ 27 hidden modules`. What does it mean by this? Is it detecting global constants that I'm using without requiring them?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Webpack hides modules coming from folders like [`["node_modules", "bower_components", "jam", "components"]`](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/commit/992231a1c82f698d37f8b619f59a78099db2293e) in your console output by default. This helps you to focus on *your modules* instead on your dependencies.

You can display them by using the `--display-modules` argument.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to set this `--display-modules` flag via the webpack config file?

Comment: In package.json you can put: "scripts": {"build": "webpack --display-modules"}

Comment: Why do most of the modules begin with "./~/" such as "./~/react/react.js"?

Comment: ~ is a shortcut for a "modules directory" which is `node_modules` in 99.99% :)

Comment: @LasseChristiansen use `stats: {maxModules: Infinity, exclude: undefined}`

Comment: @4vanger Did you put these in your webpack config?  Also what version of webpack are you running?

Comment: I had to employ all of these in the webpack config to get the equivalent of `--display-modules` nowadays: `stats: { excludeModules: false, maxModules: Infinity, exclude: undefined, modules: true }`

Comment: @ecmanaut: Can you post it as an answer? All is good except `maxModules`, my webpack doesn't know what it is.